# Merge the lay-buddhism and laity tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags on the main site, [lay-buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lay-buddhism) and [laity](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laity) tags.

Neither has a description (i.e. a wiki summary).

Do they mean the same thing? Should they be merged, with being one be made a synonym of the other?

They might be quite important/useful tags for some users.

Answer (score 2):

To me these are different concepts.

[lay-buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lay-buddhism). A Buddhist sect/movement without a significant monastic component e.g. Triratna Buddhist Community (where I practice)

[laity](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laity) - the lay community within any Buddhist school or sect

I have to say though the I'm not sure whether they are used like that but I see the concepts as different. If they are going to be useful then I think they should have a tag wiki each and probably I bit of retagging is required. I'd be happy to do that or defer to yourself as you see fit.

Hope that's useful

**EDIT**

Actually I notice that the [lay-buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lay-buddhism) tag now has a description which is different from my definition which might invalidate my comments

Comment: Thank you for answering. Don't worry about the new wiki description, because it was added very recently therefore didn't influence how the tags were used. Thanks for explaining that concept of 'lay-buddhism'. Is that concept applicable (would that meaning of a tag be useful) to many of the topics on the main site? Is it important/useful to distinguish it from 'laity'? If we keep two tags then would it be generally possible to tell which tag (laity or lay-buddhism) to use, e.g. in a question about, I don't know, sexuality?

Comment: Is that a common/conventional use of the term "lay buddhism"? https://www.google.com/search?q="lay+buddhism" suggests not, that 'lay buddhism' just implies 'laity'. SGI calls itself explicitly [a lay Buddhist movement](http://www.sgi.org/about-us/what-is-sgi.html) but maybe Triratna says [Neither monastic nor lay, we are simply Buddhists](https://thebuddhistcentre.com/text/what-triratna-buddhist-community).